# Raspberry Pi .bat Equivalent

Tags: linux, terminal, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I recently put together my first Raspberry Pi 3. I want to be able to safely shut down the Pi without corrupting the SD card. I found code online to shut it down:

`sudo shutdown -h now`

I'm wondering how to paste this into a new text file, and save that file so that it can be opened to shut down the computer, in the way that one can use a .bat file on windows to run commands.

It's running Raspbian.

Comment: That's exactly what you do. What part is unclear?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help r. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Create a text file like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Save it under /usr/local/bin possibly with an extension ".sh"; perhaps the name could be "myshutdown.sh".

Then you must give execution permission to that file, with chmod +x "thatfile", or with a graphical tool.

Now you can type "myshutdown.sh" in a console, or make a link (launcher) from the desktop to that file.

Anyway, in unix and similar, "shell scripts" are the equivalent (but better) to m$ .bat files. They don't need to have a particular exstension, even if ".sh" can be nice; but they MUST have "execution permission" (given for example using chmod(1)). Also: the first line, "#!/bin/sh" is not always necessary, but it is best to use it.